# Biztalk - MSMQ messages are being lost intermittently while receiving from queue in remote server

Tags: warnings, biztalk, msmq, event-log

I keep receiving below warning messages in event viewer .  If there is any  message being received from the queue  at the time of warning then message is being lost . Surprisingly while sending message to the queue he message is not getting lost . Biztalk ports are configured to send and receive message from queue .

The description for Event ID 5740 from source BizTalk Server cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

> MSMQ The remote procedure call failed and did not execute.
>
> The handle is invalid

this is happening in production  Can not afford more message loss.

Answer (score 0):

there are some known issues, look at this thread :
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/519e915a-488e-48bf-bd6c-8e5892689e83/failed-to-connect-to-remote-private-queue?forum=biztalkgeneral